# Understanding the Python `id` Function Across Interpreters

Tags: python, memory

I have noticed that when calling the `id` function in Python, that some values have a consistent value across all interpreter instances. I understand that Python keeps integers under 256 in memory, but I do not understand why those memory addresses would not be different in a separate interpreter instance.

For example, in interpreter 1, this is what I get:

```
>>> id(1)
140721106546944
```

For interpreter 2 running in a different command prompt, I get the same value.

What is the logic behind this?

Comment: So are these addresses are not unique across every application? I see that the ref count for `1` is different in each interpreter, so it must not be using the same actual memory space.

Answer (score -2):

The answer reside in the python optimisation that are hidden for the programmer, in fact the basic values like small number,string float etc.. are already created and stored py python when you ask one of them it will not be created but only linked to the created one so it will olway be the same.

Comment: this isn't true for `float`, actually, and the OP already understands that there is a small integer cache. They are asking why the `id` doesn't change for each new interpreter process